# How to embed an interactive Jupyter Notebook on Wordpress?

Tags: python, wordpress, github, jupyter-notebook, embed

I used WP-Push to embed this Jupyter notebook on my WordPress site. But how do I make it interactive?

I have attached a screenshot of the embedded notebook below.

[image: Check out this page at http://www.materialsinformatics.org/interactive-plots/]

If this is possible via any other notebook services, I am ready to adapt to it. Just that it should be preferably free to use.